# onclick variable is not passing to a form

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a newbie to Javascript and from what I've read I assume there is a much better way to my approach, but here it goes.

I have a form with onclick such that when a clear image is clicked on in a table cell, the background pic of the cell changes (showing that it has been selected, or unselected if clicked again). That all works, now I want to define some variable so that when the form's Submit button is pressed, a form variable is passed showing whether or not the user selected that option.

The functional javascript I found on the internet:

```
var curPic1 = 0;
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('clear-kayangan').onclick=function() {
        curPic1 = (curPic1 == 0)? 1 : 0;
        document.getElementById('td_kayangan').style.backgroundImage = (curPic1 == 1)? 'url("pics/map-kayangan-lake-selected.png")' : 'url("pics/map-kayangan-lake.png")';
    }
}
```

My plan was to write an IF statement stating if `curPic1 == 1` (the background image chosen shows that the user has selected), I would create a Global variable which I could then pass on to php in the form:

```
$spot1 = "<script>document.write(spot1);</script>";
if ($spot1 == 1) echo "<input name='spot1' type='hidden' value='1' />";
```

For testing purposes I tried:

```
$spot1=$_POST['spot1'];
if ($spot1=="1") echo "<b>This really works</b><br>";
```

and it works if I use If `$spot1==0`, whereby at the top of my javascript function I tried the following:

```
int spot1;
spot1=0;
var spot1=0;
```

and within the javascript function itself I tried:

```
int spot1 = 1;
spot1 = 1;
window.spot1 = 1;
```

I haven't yet tried the IF statement because I'm just trying to test things if they work. I read that I was supposed to be able to establish a Global variable from within a function. I added the various options above one at a time. It works with `spot=0`, so I assume the problem is that it is not being set as a Global variable within the function? Or perhaps there is a better approach to all this?

On Submit the hidden form variables will eventually be passed to another page and used there.

Comment: JavaScript with `int`?

Comment: include HTML markup as well

Comment: In Javascript, there is no "int" type. You can use parseInt() to search a string and return an integer.

Comment: I just read somewhere on Stack that I should define it as an integer or type. Anyway, even after removing it, it still works with spot1=0 but not with 1. Which html markup should I include?

Answer (score 0):

Declare hidden variable in the form, and set it's value to 0 or 1 in onclick fuction of image. When form is submitted, this value will also be passed to server

Comment: I'm new to javascript, how do I set the value "in onclick function of image"? The hidden variable is already within the form.

Comment: Note that when the image is clicked on again, it becomes "unselected" again.

Answer (score 0):

as @santosh-sawant said, you should add an id to the hidden input and change the value in the same click handler you already have, like:

```
<?php 
    $spot1 = $_POST['spot1']=='1' ? 1 : 0;
?>
<input name="spot1" id="spot1" type="hidden" value="<?=$spot1?>">
```

and then in your JS:

```
var curPic1 = 0;
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('clear-kayangan').onclick = function() {
        curPic1 = (curPic1 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
        document.getElementById('td_kayangan').style.backgroundImage = curPic1 ? 'url("pics/map-kayangan-lake-selected.png")' : 'url("pics/map-kayangan-lake.png")';

        document.getElementById('spot1').value = curPic1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that explained it! been reading some tutorials and haven't quite got my head around javascript yet, thanks a lot!